# Do I need a license to flight test a homebuilt seaplane at very low altitude?

Tags: regulations, seaplane, canada

I am asking this because me and my friends are building a homemade seaplane or boat whatever you want to call it. It's not designed for long-range or high-altitude flights. We're not going to fly at a typical altitude of normal planes/seaplanes but we're just flying it to test it. Do we require a license to fly it?

This is in Canada and it's a manned aircraft.

Comment: How big/ heavy is it?

Comment: take a look at ultra-light category, if your build matched the description you might be able to fly it without a license.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I edited your question to - hopefully! - make it a little clearer. If I got it wrong, feel free to edit again or roll back. The [tour] may be helpful if you're new to StackExchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

14 CFR §1.1 defines an aircraft as “means a device that is used or intended to be used for flight in the air.”  Flying boats are intended for flight in the air.  Therefore.....

Comment: I'm not sure that this answers the question. There are a number of things defined as an aircraft by 14 CFR 1.1 (for example a Drone, an Ultralight, hang glider, powered parachute, or even a kite) that do not require a license to fly.

Comment: Also, the OP says it's not going to fly "at an average height of normal planes/seaplanes" (whatever that means), so maybe it's a hovercraft or ekranoplan?

Comment: The OP added the information that this is about Canadian regulations.

Comment: I'm puzzled how an answer citing a US regulation can be helpful to someone in Canada. It's certainly possible that Canada has a very similar definition, but *this answer* on its own is about the US.